# VBA Error 424 Object Required on call to sub in Workbook_Open

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to vba. I am getting a 424 Ojbect required error when I open the document. I tried using Call subName but that made no difference.

Please let me know what else I can send or explain.

Code found in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Sheet1.Worksheet_Activate//<- Object Required
   Sheet2.Worksheet_Activate
   Sheet3.Worksheet_Activate
   Sheet4.Worksheet_Activate
   Sheet5.Worksheet_Activate
   Sheet6.Worksheet_Activate
   Sheet7.Worksheet_Activate
...
```

Code found in Sheet1:

```
'INITIAL SETUP OF THE SHEET
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Sheet9.Range("B1").Text = "TRUE" Then
    'RUN INIT FUNCTIONS HERE
    Me.initReqLink
    Me.initVersion
    Me.initCbApplicaiton

    Sheet9.Range("B1").Text = "FALSE"

  End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you declaring Sheet1 As Worksheet? "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")."

Comment: Event handlers are `Private` by default for a reason: they're not meant to be invoked manually like this, see [braX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598326/1188513). @danieltakeshi `Sheet1` would be the `CodeName` identifier, a free, global-scope object variable identifier VBA creates for every worksheet in an Excel project. No need to declare it and fetch it from `ThisWorkbook` every time. Also fetching a worksheet by name is extremely frail, since users can rename sheets on a whim.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't know! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be invoking event handlers manually, but that's not why you're having that error; by making the method `Public` you've exposed it onto `Sheet1`'s interface, making these calls perfectly "legal" - so the methods *do* get invoked, no doubt.

Go to Tools / Options / General / Error Trapping, and set it to *Break on Unhandled Errors*.

Then you should have a better idea of exactly which statement is blowing up, most likely located somewhere in one of these:

```
Me.initReqLink
Me.initVersion
Me.initCbApplicaiton
```

..which you haven't posted.

Side note, `Call` doesn't make a difference, because it's an obsolete syntax that hasn't had a purpose since the advent of the *implicit call syntax* way back when. You never *need* an explicit `Call` statement. Never.

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to `Sheet1.Activate` and that event will be called.

Comment: Pretty sure the event handlers *do* get invoked. OP's IDE probably isn't breaking in class modules, which hides the real problem. But kudos for making Excel invoke the events rather than explicitly calling them.